# Deleting key to nested object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65571240/how-to-expand-single-level-nested-hashes-on-the-fly) I got some excellent answers, but it turned out I had over simplified the problem I am facing.

I have the same object

```
const obj = {
  a: 'A',
  b: {
    bb: 'BB',
    bbb: 'BBB',
    },
  c: 'C'
};
```

and I somehow need to end up with

```
{ a: 'A', bb: 'BB', bbb: 'BBB', c: 'C' }
```

where there key to the nested object is removed. It doesn't have to be in place. Creating a new object is fine.

## Question

Can anyone figure out how to delete the key from the nested object, but still keep the nested object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten it recursively:

```js
function flattenObject(obj) {
    const ret = {};
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof val === "object") {
            Object.assign(ret, flattenObject(val));
        } else {
            ret[key] = val;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get an array of [key, value] pairs using `Object.entries()`. Iterate the pairs with `Array.flatMap()`. If the value is object, call the function with the value. If not return an object of `{ [key]: value }`. Merge to a single object by spreading the array of object into `Object.assign()`.

Use recursion and merge the sub objects by spreading into `Object.assign()`:

```js
const fn = obj => Object.assign({},
  ...Object.entries(obj)
    .flatMap(([k, v]) => typeof(v) === "object" ? fn(v) : { [k]: v })
);

const j = { a: 'A', b: { bb: 'BB', bbb: 'BBB' }, c: 'C' };

const result = fn(j);

console.log(result);
```

Another option is to work directly with the `[key, value]` entries (`p`), and then convert everything to a single object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const fn = obj =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .flatMap(p => typeof(p[1]) === "object" ? fn(p[1]) : [p])

const j = { a: 'A', b: { bb: 'BB', bbb: 'BBB' }, c: 'C' };

const result = Object.fromEntries(fn(j));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Isn't using `Object.assign` and the spread operator redundant? Would it be better to use an object literal? (Good answer btw)

Comment: In this case you want to merge an array of objects, and spreading an array into an object won't work, so you need to spread the array, so the objects would be the parameters of the assign. Try it - spread `[{ a: 1}, { b: 2 }]` into an object, and into `Object.assign()`, and see the difference.